# Passwordless Authentiacation with access token for Mobile

Tags: onelogin

I would like to create passwordless authentication using SMS.
When user write his username he would get an sms with otp code.
after user write the otp code he would get access token. 
We are using native mobile apps.

How can I achieve that?
I read the docs on https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/multi-factor-authentication/overview#

on step 7 'Grant access when verification returns success.' I am struggling to understand how can I create access/refresh token or Authorization code for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the [Twilio SMS Factor](https://onelogin.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=e32a9943db109700d5505eea4b961908)

Then you are able to use the [activate-factor](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/multi-factor-authentication/activate-factor) to trigger the SMS and then use the 
[verify_factor](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/multi-factor-authentication/verify-factor) method to validate the OTP value introduced by the user.

The "7. Grant access when verification returns success" means that if the SMS OTP token was valid, then you may consider that the user passed the authentication validation process so you may authenticate the user on the native mobile app.